# Trying to run GCompris on my new Raspberry Pi 4 doesn't work

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, games

I bought an RPi 4 recently for my son to play GCompris and other educational games. My daughter has an exactly similar setup since before, which works well. When I install RPi OS and then GCompris I can start the game, but as soon as I click on a button anywhere in the game it hangs and won't proceed.

I am unsure on how to proceed to debug this issue. Does anyone recognize the issue I am having, or have an idea of what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently it has a bug.(likely to be a firmware issue with sound driver)

start it with the -m option to turn off sound

either from a command shell or click the menu option with right mouse button to go into edit mode for the entry and adjust properties, desktop entry and put a
-m option at the end of the command (ensure you have a space before that -m !!)

Comment: Yep, that works! A shame it doesn't work with sound though, any idea of when that might be fixed? Also odd that it works on the other RPi4 I have it installed on without the '-m' flag (still no sound though). Luckily I found it on Android, so they can play it with sound there until it gets fixed for the Pi. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have installed gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio package ---
this other solved cases (https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/1516)
and should allow you to play with the sounds.

Answer (score 1):

To successfully run `./gcrompris-qt.sh` on my Raspberry Pi 400, I needed to do these commands first:

```
sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio
sudo apt install libpulse-mainloop-glib0
```